# What is the nature of a class property when declared with "= {}()" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have a Swift class from some sample code, and within it there is a property `captureSession` declared like so:

```
private lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession = {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()

    guard
        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
        else { return session }
    session.addInput(input)
    return session
}()
```

**I don't think `captureSession` is a computed property, neither is it a closure. Then what is it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`captureSession` is lazy property but `={}()` is not regarding lazy initialization.
It is `Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function`. This is an example.

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 14)
    return label
}()
```

You can find more information at the end of this [document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html).

Comment: In the doc it says: _"Note that the closure’s end curly brace is followed by an empty pair of parentheses. This tells Swift to execute the closure immediately."_, that is what I missed!

Answer (score 3):

This is **Lazy initialisation**. It is often used when initial value is relatively expensive to create. So you create value when you sure you need it. So `captureSession` will be created when you access it first time and then stored in `captureSession` variable.

The syntax `={}()` depicts a closure (anonymous function) which is called when you access your property. This closure return Type is `AVCaptureSession`.

Other words: Using `lazy var a: SomeType = { ... }()` you postpone object `a` creation until you really need it. When you access it first time, the variable `a` will take a result of the closure.

---

I like the explanation written [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-lazy-property-initialization/), [Official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) can also be helpful.

Comment: The `= { ... }()` syntax is not part of the lazy initialization in any way though. You can use it even for normal variables and on the other hand, you don't need it for `lazy` variables.

Comment: @Sulthan, the `= {...}()` is just a way to write closure result assigned to variable. I was answering in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Lazy properties allow you to create certain parts of a Swift type when needed, rather than doing it as part of its initialization process. This can be useful in order to avoid optionals, or to improve performance when certain properties might be expensive to create. It can also help with keeping initializers more clean, since you can defer some of the setup of your types until later in their lifecycle.

In simple words captureSession instance won't be created until you access it the first time, and after instantiation will return the same instance everytime.

The advantage of this approach is that you can keep both the property declaration and its setup in one place.

Here's a nice article on lazy initialization: [Using lazy properties in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-lazy-properties-in-swift)